# Find AD users with specific AD attribute NOT null

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a script/Powershell command that will list all AD users that have a value *not* NULL in the teletexterminalidentifier attribute, so they must have a value set.

By default this attribute is not set but we have an app that modifies this attribute (to contain a hexadecimal string), so I'm looking for a list of all users that have this attribute set to something.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yeah, but I think I finally figured it out, mostly by reading help files :)

Get-ADUser -Filter 'teletexterminalidentifier -ge 0' | Export-Csv c:\list.csv
Seems to work.
How do I do the same thing, but export the value of the teletexterminalidentifier attribute at the same time?

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to get the users by using:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'teletexterminalidentifier -like "*"'
```

You can then filter what you need by piping the command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'teletexterminalidentifier -like "*"' | Select-Object name,teletexterminalidentifier | Export-Csv file.csv
```

Where `Select-Object` lets you select what fields you want to get the info from by name.

Comment: Unfortunately I get
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ''teletexterminalidentifier' -like '*'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.

Comment: Did you import the module?

Comment: Yes. When I change the command to 
Get-ADUser -Filter 'teletexterminalidentifier -like "*"' | export-csv c:\list6.csv
it works. Just a slight re-working of the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is the Where-Object cmdlet.  Here's some pseudo code to help you:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.teletexterminalidentifier -ne $null} | Export-Csv c:\list.csv
```

Comment: That command is prompting me to supply values for "Filter"
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop> Get-ADUser | Where-Object {$_.teletexterminalidentifier -ne $null} | Export-Csv c:\list4.csv
cmdlet Get-ADUser at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Filter:

Comment: @Johan I added the filter param to the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter users based on this property, you have to add the `-properties` switch to the `Get-ADuser` Cmdlet. Indeed, without this switch, it loads only basic properties (members) for user objects.

Thus, here is the full command to achieve what you want :

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties * | ? {$_.teletexterminalidentifier -ne $null} | Select-Object CN,SamAccountName,Teletexterminalidentifier
```

It will produce this kind of result :
[image]

Then you will be able to export the result into the desired format.

Hope this helps !